# Efeito de escala de cinza em slide carousel

Tags: css, html5, slide

Pessoal estou com uma dúvida alguém conhece algum plugin que faça com esse efeito do meu layout? preciso que as fotos fiquem em escala de cinza e somente quando ela estiver no meio seja a cor normal não sei se da para fazer isso com o `owl-carousel`ou se existe algum plugin pronto que faça isso:
se houver algum plugin ou material de estudo podem me passar por favor.

Segue link do [site](http://www.deepocean.com.br/2018/)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Jovem posta o seu CSS e o HTML inteiro ai inclusive com a `<head>`

Comment: @hugocsl Adicionei o link do servidor de testes com o site na pergunta acessa lá

Comment: Sem o Carrocel dos clientes na página não da pra te ajudar...

Comment: @hugocsl então eu ainda nao fiz porque to pesquisando aqui se da apra fazer com owl carousel isso ou se já tem algum outro plugin que faça entende?

Comment: existe uma maneira, com css vc deixa todas as imagens em escala cinza, quando chegar na imagem central, em destaque, com o owl carousel vc insere uma classe que deixa ele na cor normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

você aplica o `filter: grayscale(1)` em todos os items do carousel, no item que é aplicado as classes "**.center**" e "**.active**" automaticamente pelo plugin, você aproveita para aplicar novamente o `filter` mas com valor `none`.

link da solução: https://codepen.io/leandroruel/pen/WMbMPZ

html:

```
<div class="owl-carousel">
  <div><img src="//placehold.it/300x150/936/fff/?text=1" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="//placehold.it/300x150/693/fff/?text=2" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="//placehold.it/300x150/369/fff/?text=3" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="//placehold.it/300x150/f63/fff/?text=4" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.owl-item {
  filter: grayscale(1);
}

.owl-item.active.center {
  filter: none;
}
```

js:

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  autoplay: true,
  center: true,
  loop: true,
  nav: true,
});
```